# Did a BBC headline originally misspell “analyst” as “analcyst”?

Tags: media, social-media

Back in 2017, a number of tweets circulated ostensibly showing a Facebook embed of a BBC headline with an unfortunate typo. An example of such a Tweet:

https://twitter.com/ClaireHammond/status/823100058304397312

Many more tweets about this typo can be found when searching Twitter for the hashtag #analcyst.

The relevant part of the image is found below:

[image: A picture of Nigel Farage, a prominent UK politician, with below it the headline "Nigel Farage hired by Fox News as a political analcyst - BBC News"]

The claim is [repeated](https://www.theneweuropean.co.uk/brexit-news/48-things-you-need-to-know-about-nigel-farage-22370) (without a screenshot) by *The New European*:

> He was the subject of the most unfortunate, and yet the most accurate, typo in recent history on the BBC News website: 'Nigel Farage hired by Fox News as a political analcyst'.

In addition, aplin.co.uk [claims](https://apiln.co.uk/the-bbc-accidentally-called-nigel-farage-an-anal-cyst/) that

> Although the Beeb [BBC] were very quick to update the headline at their end, they weren’t quite so prompt in getting Facebook to refresh the headline that it automatically grabs.
>
> The end result was that their many, many, many Facebook followers were presented with this absolute gem of a howler.

The original article at https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-38695203 has the correct spelling, but did the headline ever include the typo?

Comment: The [earliest webarchive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20170120214446/https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-38695203) has *analyst*, which would suggest *if* there was an error, it was corrected in the two hours before it was archived, not proving the point either way

Comment: I've seen typos on the BBC but I can't remember any that would not have been caught by a dictionary spell check (as opposed to a grammar check like the ["atomic typos"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error#Atomic_typos)). Since "analcyst" is not a dictionary word, the claim looks a bit implausible to me.

Comment: This has the feel of a joke, and thus Poe enticed you to question the reality of it.

Comment: I see there are some versions in which it's claimed Fox News made this typo. https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FC3GEOJeXcAAEWRB.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fhashtag%2Fanalcyst&tbnid=41UxJxFAj2dNVM&vet=12ahUKEwjIsfnVgcfuAhXx7uAKHeosBuEQMygFegQIARAi..i&docid=MnsdwDKcNwErJM&w=795&h=568&q=farage%20analcyst&ved=2ahUKEwjIsfnVgcfuAhXx7uAKHeosBuEQMygFegQIARAi So it does seem like an urban legend.

Comment: I'm on the same side of the urban legend side.  The letter c on the keyboard is nowhere near the l or y keys on the keyboard.  Hell they're not even the same hand.  The only letter close is the s, but it's the wrong finger and the s is on the home row.

Comment: @DenisS: the alternative may be that someone working at the BBC intentionally trolled Farage with this "typo", knowing/hoping it would create a meme.